# Upgrading PHP in XAMPP for linux?

Tags: php, linux, xampp

How can I upgrade my current php (only) in xampp?

I need to upgrade from  5.3.1 to 5.4.0

Comment: Current stable version of PHP is 5.3.8 and I recommend to upgrade the xampp itself.

Comment: PHP 5.4.0 is in RC development, wait until PHP release stable version, than the XAMPP for linux will get (most probably) official update

Comment: I cannot wait, as there is a feature that php 5.4.0 supports which we really need which is bandwidth limiting in curl – Imran Omar Bukhsh

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Download PHP's source code and extract it in /usr/src:

```
cd ~/downloads
wget http://snaps.php.net/php5.4-latest.tar.gz
tar -xzf php5.4-latest.tar.gz 
sudo mv php5.4 /usr/src/php-5.4
```

You need to find the configuration of already installed version , so you can use it and install the new version with the exact same configuration

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php --info | grep "Configure Command"
```

You should see something like this as result :

```
./configure '--prefix=/opt/lampp' '--with-apxs2=/opt/lampp/bin/apxs' '--with-config-file-path=/opt/lampp/etc' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--disable-debug'
```

Actually, list should probably be much more longer. Copy and store it as you will need to use it as a whole later.

Make a backup of the current installation, in case if anything goes wrong

```
sudo cp -r /opt/lampp /opt/lampp.bak
```

Now that you have configuration options, review it and then use it to compile the new version.

```
cd /usr/src/php-5.4/
./configure  --prefix=/opt/lampp --with-apxs2=/opt/lampp/bin/apxs --with-config-file-path=/opt/lampp/etc --with-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-inline-optimization --disable-debug 
make 
make install
```

Run `/opt/lampp/bin/php -v` in order to make sure you have correct php version installed. It should be 5.4.0 Beta.

Comment: Great post, thank you. For my setup I had to recompile imap (http://www.brighterlamp.com/2012/12/how-to-compile-php-with-imap-support/) install pam-devel, postgresql-devel packages and change the --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/opt/lampp/lib/instantclient-11.2.0.3.0 parameter

Answer (score 3):

Just want to complement @altern answer....

When I tried all the indications exactly in line of

```
make install
```

I had an error in the output

```
Installing PHP SAPI module:       apache2handler
/opt/lampp/build/instdso.sh SH_LIBTOOL='/opt/lampp/build/libtool' libphp7.la /opt/lampp/modules
/opt/lampp/build/libtool --mode=install install libphp7.la /opt/lampp/modules/
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 3215: /opt/lampp/build/libtool: install_prog+=install: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 3235: /opt/lampp/build/libtool: files+= libphp5.la: not found
libtool: install: you must specify an install program
libtool: install: Try `libtool --help --mode=install' for more information.
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

After looking for information to solve, I found a japanese link:
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Kenji_s/touch/searchdiary?word=*%5BUbuntu%5D

What I did to solve it after trying to understand this japanese solution was simply:

```
sudo nano /opt/lampp/build/libtool
```

And when the editor was opened I changed the first line, instead of:

```
#! /bin/sh
```

I wrote:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

After that I tried again

```
make install
```

And voila it compiled!

Hope It helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Now **XAMPP** is supporting **PHP 5.4** and **PHP 5.5**. You can now download installer of your required version of PHP from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html

Thanks.