# Upgrade PHP to 5.6 from 5.5 in LAMPP for Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, lampp

Ubuntu Version : 14.04

There is existing LAMPP installation under /opt/lampp with PHP5.5

I needed to only update to PHP 5.6.
Followed below steps but is failing in make install step

```
cd ~/downloads
wget http://ar2.php.net/distributions/php-5.6.17.tar.gz
tar -xzf php-5.6.17.tar.gz
sudo mv php-5.6.17 /usr/src/php-5.6.17
```

/opt/lampp/bin/php --info | grep "Configure Command"

```
./configure  --prefix=/opt/lampp --with-apxs2=/opt/lampp/bin/apxs --with-config-file-path=/opt/lampp/etc --with-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-inline-optimization --disable-debug --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-ctype --enable-ftp --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-magic-quotes --enable-shmop --disable-sigchild --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-wddx --with-gdbm=/opt/lampp --with-jpeg-dir=/opt/lampp --with-png-dir=/opt/lampp --with-freetype-dir=/opt/lampp --with-zlib=yes --with-zlib-dir=/opt/lampp --with-openssl=/opt/lampp --with-xsl=/opt/lampp --with-ldap=/opt/lampp --with-gd --with-imap=/bitnami/xamppunixinstallerstackDev-linux-x64/src/imap-2007e --with-imap-ssl --with-gettext=/opt/lampp --with-mssql=/opt/lampp --with-sybase-ct=/opt/lampp --with-mysql-sock=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/opt/lampp/lib/instantclient --with-mcrypt=/opt/lampp --with-mhash=/opt/lampp --enable-sockets --enable-mbstring=all --with-curl=/opt/lampp --enable-mbregex --enable-zend-multibyte --enable-exif --with-bz2=/opt/lampp --with-sqlite=shared,/opt/lampp --with-sqlite3=/opt/lampp --with-libxml-dir=/opt/lampp --enable-soap --enable-pcntl --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pgsql=shared,/opt/lampp/ --with-iconv=/opt/lampp --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-pdo-pgsql=/opt/lampp/postgresql --with-pdo-sqlite --with-icu-dir=/opt/lampp --enable-fileinfo --enable-phar --enable-zip --enable-intl
```

Then this is done -

```
./configure [ whole above command ]
make
```

Running make install gives error -

```
Installing PHP SAPI module:       apache2handler
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
make: *** [install-sapi] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/username/php --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
$ mkdir /home/username/php/etc/apache2/mods-available
$ make
$ INSTALL_ROOT=/home/username/php PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH make install
```

1) --prefix is necessary to install most of PHP under your home directory.

2) --with-apxs2 is necessary to tell PHP where to find apxs2. For some reason (probably presence of --prefix) you must indicate this even if apxs2 is in your $PATH.

3) The mkdir is necessary to create the directory where apxs2 will place the PHP module .load file.

4) INSTALL_ROOT is an undocumented variable which overrides some install locations that for some reason do not conform to --prefix.

5) Adding /usr/sbin to $PATH is necessary on systems where a2enmod is not in regular users’ $PATH.

http://blog.thecybershadow.net/2013/01/25/installing-php-and-apache-module-under-home/

Comment: i tried this but gave same error - INSTALL_ROOT=/opt/lampp PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH make install

Comment: should intsall_root be /opt/lampp/php or whereever your PHP resides in? Basically should match the --prefix directory.

Comment: i was following instruction from below where prefix is being obtained from php -info which is pointing to /opt/lampp : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740817/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-linux

Comment: Please add the error you get and the configuration file.